# Show Networks Flyout (the "connect-to-network" thingie) without explorer.exe running

Tags: windows-8, wifi, windows-shell, windows-explorer, kiosk-mode

Requirements:

1. Our application replaces the usual windows shell (explorer.exe). This is a product requirement for a closed system that we're supplying.
2. We oughtta let the user select a wi-fi network and connect to it.

The problem: The wi-fi networks dialog only shows up when explorer.exe is running

What we tried:

1. Write our own wi-fi manager that uses wlan API. It lists connectible networks and allows the user to connect/disconnect. Problem: too many network types/configuratons that have to be tested, especially when the wheel has already been invented and reinvented all over.
2. Try and check how is the networks dialog implemented. It appears that it's and undocumented COM interface (IUIRAdioManager). Problem: it's undocumented, so no API
3. Use an existing network manager, for instance the one that comes with the driver. Problems: it's ugly, not to the product's taste; and it opens too many options for the user, like creating and loading profiles, browsing for files on a file system - these things are unacceptable.
4. Running explorer.exe just for the purpose of showing the networks dialog and then killing it. Problem: once we run explorer.exe - it pops up metro view and hides our fullscreen application or shows the taskbar.

The latter seems like the preferred solution: no need to reinvent the wheel, it does what's needed. Just gotta make explorer.exe not pop out, keep it quiet in the background.

So, we're down to two options:

1. How to show the networks flyout dialog without explorer.exe?
2. How to run explorer.exe without it popping out metro or taskbar above our application?

Comment: I doubt either of your two options are possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your first solution would be incredibly difficult to implement. I am almost certain that the Networks window is dependent on explorer.

However, your second is entirely possible.

1. To hide the taskbar, you will need to find a window (using `FindWindowEx`) to find the taskbar (name is `Shell_traywnd`). This will hide the taskbar and start button. EDIT: Unless you are implementing your own taskbar, you might want to set the taskbar to autohide.
2. Next you will need to hide all of the metro programs. In a similar fashion as above, find the class named `EdgeUiInputWndClass` and close it. You should be able to get the process name of it and then kill the process.
3. Windows key. This is a little more difficult. You will probably need to use a [program](https://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/) and delete the key or a keyboard hook (a low level keyboard hook) and just ignore key presses with the same scancode as the windows key. Left Windows is 0x5b and Right is 0x5c ([source](https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/kbd/scancodes-1.html)). Note that this will not block <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>.
4. Finally, to show the Flyout, you can run `%windir%\explorer.exe shell:::{38A98528-6CBF-4CA9-8DC0-B1E1D10F7B1B}`
    ([source](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/10190-networks-flyout-shortcut-create-windows-8-a.html)). 
   EDIT2:
5. You should also be able to hide toast notifications via [this](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/7621-toast-notifications-enable-disable-windows-8-a.html)
   Of course, I don't see why you cannot just use Windows 8/8.1 and put the app in [kiosk mode](http://www.howtogeek.com/173562/how-to-easily-put-a-windows-pc-into-kiosk-mode-with-assigned-access/).